# Finding time with an initial velocity of $29 \frac{ft}{s}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A ball is thrown at an initial height of $3$ feet with an initial upward velocity at $29 \frac{ft}{s}$. The ball's height $h$ (in feet) after $t$ seconds is given by: $h= 3 + 29t -16t^2$. Find the values of t if the ball's height is $15ft$. Round your answer(s) to the nearest hundredth.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

I think my answer of $1.17$ and $0.64$ is correct but I just want confirmation so I am confident in my answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $t\approx1.17$ and $t\approx0.64$ are indeed solutions to $3+29t-16t^2=15$

Comment: Your answers appear to be correct.  But I suggest you give us some indication of how you arrived at those answers if you would like us to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I solved it using the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's confirm your solutions so that you are confident in them, and so that others can learn how to solve this problem.
$$h=3+29t-16t^2$$
We want to calculate $t$ when the ball is at a height of $15$ feet. Note that the ball will be at the same height twice (once going up and once coming down), except for when it reaches its apex, so we will likely have two different solutions.
\begin{align}
-16t^2+29t+3&=15\\-16t^2+29t-12&=0
\end{align}
Let us apply the quadratic formula to this equation with $a=-16$, $b=29$, and $c=-12$.
$$t=\frac{-(29)\pm\sqrt{(29)^2-4(-16)(-12)}}{2(-16)}=\frac{-29\pm\sqrt{841-768}}{-32}=\frac{-29\pm\sqrt{73}}{-32}$$
After calculating these two expressions, we arrive at our answers.
$$t=\frac{-29+\sqrt{73}}{-32}\approx0.64\\t=\frac{-29-\sqrt{73}}{-32}\approx1.17$$
Let's check for extraneous solutions and further verify the results with more accurate approximations of $t$.
$$h=3+29(0.63925)-16(0.63925)^2=15.000001$$
$$h=3+29(1.17325)-16(1.17325)^2=15.000001$$
You solved the problem correctly—good job.